# How to adjust html/css layout for instagram in-app browser?

Tags: android, html, css, instagram

I've been googling a lot, but found no clue for my problem. I have a tiny website (html/css only), that's looks nice on mobile Chrome. But on instagram in-app browser on Android 5.0 somethings goes wrong with paddings. Is there any way to deal with in-app browsers through media-queries or prefixes? So far I've found just nothing. Hope here someone could help me. Thanks in advance.

P.S. Sorry for my poor English, I am working on it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use JavaScript to detect the user-agent which includes `Instagram` and request a specific CSS for that case.

Example code:

```
<script>
var isInstagram = navigator.userAgent.match(/instagram/i);
if (isInstagram) {
  var head = document.querySelector('head');
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = 'your-file-with-instagram-fixes.css';
  head.appendChild(link);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late to the party but I just struggled with IG browser rendering a modal to fit the screen.  Turns out the issue was the .webp images I was using.  Replaced them with png's and all is good now.  I used Tom Roggero's code to identify IG browser then replaced the img src attributes using JS.  Hope that helps someone!