# Any workaround on Instagram in-app browser cropping?

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css

Instagram released (at some point this year) an update on their in-app browser (webview) that at least in iOS, breaks most sites.

The attached image is the website opened after clicking the "Learn more" on an Ad, but has the same behavior also on Profile Bio links.

The problem? It seems the top bar is an overlay on the website, making most navigations for mobile (hamburger icon on top left corner) unusable/unclickable and/or hidden.

The `innerHeight` is the same as `screen.height`. As answered at [How to adjust html/css layout for instagram in-app browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40926277/how-to-adjust-html-css-layout-for-instagram-in-app-browser/45697862) we can sniff the user agent of the webview.

[image: SXSW website via Instagram Ads click]

Unsure if they will fix it at some point, but seems that any padding-top kind of solution would break if they do.

Comment: Hi Tom, did you find a fix for this by chance? I'm noticing the Instagram update 2 days ago is causing this exact issue on a few of our sites. Let me know!

Comment: More specifically, what css did you write to resolve issue with your header getting cut-off? We have multiple fixed position elements having issues with their position / visibility in the instagram browser. Would love your thoughts!

Comment: @nickff I solved it using JavaScript, see my answer below. There's no CSS-only solution, as you'd have to sniff the user agent to detect their webview.

Comment: Got it. Thanks, Tom! We're noticing this issue has resurfaced on many sites (not just our own). Guessing Instagram will release a fix, as it only seems to be occurring on iOS devices and not on Android.

Comment: @nickff the fix I provided on the answers does take their future-fix into consideration, making it do nothing if they ever fix it. `available height == screen height` whenever they fix it will stop being the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found out an alternative that in theory should not break when they release a proper fix (given tons of ads are pointing to broken sites currently:)

```
if (window.innerHeight === window.screen.height && navigator.userAgent.match(/instagram/i)) {
  // here apply the fixes
}
```

Comment: And how did you fix the problem? Did you scroll your content down? How did you know the height of instagram's header?

Comment: @MichaelCauduro it's intentional to not show the "fixes" as it may be different for each website. Your solution should be for your specific website, and you can calculate the exact pixels either by trial and error, or by using a screenshot and the ruler in Photoshop or any design program.